Is sha256 quantum secure?
I've been reading about the security implications of quantum computing on cryptographic algorithms and came across some discussions regarding SHA-256. I understand that SHA-256 is currently considered secure against classical computing attacks, but I'm concerned about its security in the context of quantum computing.
Specifically, how does Grover's algorithm impact the security of SHA-256? Is there a significant reduction in security due to quantum computing, and if so, what are the practical implications? Additionally, what steps are being taken to prepare for potential quantum threats to SHA-256, and are there any recommended quantum-resistant alternatives?
I'm looking for detailed insights and any references to recent research or standards being developed to address these concerns

it seems that the folks at NSA don't think that it is.  The CNSA 2.0 standard mandates SHA-384 or SHA-512.

@Swashbuckler can you refere any material ?

@Swashbuckler: actually, CNSA 1.0 (which did not address postquantum) specifies SHA-384 - hence, the reasons that NSA did not allow SHA-256 had nothing to do with postquantum
